# launch several computation in batch in a shell

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I have 16 computation to do and I'd like to launch it in batch in order to use the 16 cores of my machine at the same time.
I'd like to do a shell script of this kind:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for i in `seq 16`
do
  cd directory$i
  <batch command>
done
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can.* You just have to ensure they run as background tasks, something like:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for i in `seq 16`
do
  cd directory$i
  <batch command> &
done
```

Without that, it will just run the jobs sequentially. You may also want to ensure you wait for them all to finish as well, by using `wait`:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for i in `seq 16` ; do
  cd directory$i
  <batch command> &
done
wait # May depends on shell, bash/ksh waits for all
```

Comment: is it necessary to do 16 wait command? In man wait I have:  wait [n ...]
              Wait  for  each  specified  process and return its termination status.   If n is not given, all currently active child processes are waited for, and the return status is zero. 
So only 1 wait at the end of the script is needed no?

Comment: @rudy: wasn't sure about `ksh` but you appear to be right (just tested). Both `bash` and `ksh` will wait for all currently active children. That of course may introduce another issue if you have other children that *aren't* in that group of sixteen. If so, you'll probably need to look into storing the PIDs and using explicit waits.

Answer (score 1):

without the need of backticks (external command)

```
#!/bin/ksh
for d in  dir{1..16}; do
    echo $d &
done
wait
echo done
```

btw schellcheck.net would say:

```
Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`
```